# Как тестировать класс с вложенными зависимыми приватными методами?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Есть класс с взаимосвязанными методами.

```
<?php

class SomeClass {

    public $a = 0;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = $this->f1();
    }

    private function f1() {
        $f2 = $this->f2();

        if ($f2 !== 6) {
            return 10;
        }

        return $f2 + 1;
    }

    private function f2() {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

Мы видим, что результат того, что будет в `$a` зависит аж от метода `f2`.

**Вопрос:** как можно в текущем случае для метода `f2` задать другое возвращаемое значение? Я мог бы замокать, но для этого метод должен быть как минимум `protected`, но в коде не задумано наследование этого класса и поэтому установка другого модификатора доступа исключена.

---

Код ниже работает нормально с protected методом (но нужно с private или какой-то другой подход)

```
class SomeClassTest extends Unit {

    use Specify;

    public function test_mock() {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeClass::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['f2'])
            ->getMock();

        $mock->method('f2')->willReturnCallback(function () { return 10; });

        $reflectedClass = new ReflectionClass(SomeClass::class);
        $constructor = $reflectedClass->getConstructor();
        $constructor->invoke($mock);

        $this->assertEquals(10, $mock->a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, стоит отделить методы f1/f2 от класса, создать другой класс, который будет рассчитывать что надо,  и внедрить этот класс как зависимость в конструктор класса `SomeClass`. В конструкторе будет тогда что-то типа `__construct(AnotherClass $ac) { $this->a = $ac->f(); }`

Comment: Дело в том, что эти методы должны, так скажем, использоваться только конкретно в этом классе. И чтобы другие классы не могли использовать эти методы. Например есть сервис создания директорий и вот это - доп методы для этого сервиса. Не хотелось бы, чтобы, условно, сервис покупки персиков мог вызвать вспомогательный метод для сервиса создания директорий

Comment: Если методы должны использоваться конкретно в этом классе, значит, они должны быть частью этого класса, разве нет? В любом случае, приватные/защищенные методы не играют роли в юнит-тестах, важно лишь то, что на входе, и что на выходе, остальное - детали реализации, которые не должны учитываться

Comment: @lezhni "значит, они должны быть частью этого класса, разве нет?" у меня так и есть, если вы посмотрите на код в вопросе. "приватные/защищенные методы не играют роли в юнит-тестах, важно лишь то, что на входе, и что на выходе, остальное - детали реализации, которые не должны учитываться"   как вы можете заметить, то, что происходит в конструкторе. или даже в методе `f1` зависит от того, что вернёт `f2`. Вопрос: как можно написать тест, чтобы в `$this->a` было разное значение в зависимости от `f2` если `f2` приватный и значение `$this->a` зависит от  возвращаемых значенией в приват методах?